# How to get Internet Explorer 7 Print Preview to default to 2 Page View?

Tags: internet-explorer-7

I'm running XP. I can't upgrade to IE8/9 or use another browser due to application compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I thing I have found so far is a keyboard shortcut:

- **Alt-F** then **Alt-V** to Print Preview
- When in Print Preview, **Alt-N** then **2** to select 2 Page View

Comment: this is is the quickest way, as there is no 'saved' setting that you can set.